# Using python to replace a single element in multiple xml files with the same element from a different set

Tags: python, xml, merge

I have two separate folders of xml; one folder contains older versions of the same records, one contains updated versions. I need to replace one element in each record in the newer set with the older. Wrinkle: the filenames do not match, and the filenames of the newer set need to be retained. That said, each record has a unique value that could be used as a key field to match files.

The element set that needs to be replaced is `<mods:name>`. Example: The following -

```
      <mods:name>
         <mods:namePart>Example creator</mods:namePart>
         <mods:role>
            <mods:roleTerm type="text">creator</mods:roleTerm>
         </mods:role>
      </mods:name>
```

Needs to be replaced with -

```
      <mods:name>
         <mods:namePart>Example creator</mods:namePart>
         <mods:role>
            <mods:roleTerm type="text">creator</mods:roleTerm>
         </mods:role>
         <mods:namePart>Example owner</mods:namePart>
         <mods:role>
            <mods:roleTerm type="text">owner</mods:roleTerm>
         </mods:role>
      </mods:name>
```

The field that can be used as a key is `<mods:identifier>` (which appears in the full files, but is not shown in these snippets). Example -

`<mods:identifier type="local">dc_031_001</mods:identifier>`

I'd like some kind of python solution, but I'm open to suggestions. Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: There's no `<mods:identifier>` in either the original or replacement xml.

Comment: Jack, ```<mods:identifier>``` appears in the full files. I only posted snippets here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import etree as ET

root = ET.getroot('old_doc')

replacement_dict = {}

identifiers = root.findall('.//mods:identifier')

for identifier in identifiers:
   #this part is a little wishy washy because I can't see the relationship between identifier element and the elements you want
   try:   
      identifier_text = identifier.text
      replacement_elem = #use a .find or a getnext or whatever depending on the relationship
      replacement_elem_text = replacement_elem.text    
      temp_dict = {identifier_text: replacement_elem_text}

root2 = ET.getroot('new_doc')

new_identifiers = root2.findall('mods:identifier')

for new_identifier in new_identifiers:
   #get both elements as before
   if new_identifier.text in replacement_dict:
      elem_to_be_replaced.text = replacement_dict.get(new_identifier_text)
```

Some of that is pseudocode but it should get you to where you need to go.